# Repairing broken RaspberryPi partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems, raspberry-pi

My RaspberryPi was acting up and I couldn't connect to it with SSH anymore, so I decided to restart it by cutting the power and plugging it back in.
When starting it showed a message with "Kernel Panic" and after some googling I found out that the partition was probably messed up.

I loaded Ubuntu from a live USB and plugged in the MicroSD card from the RaspberryPi.

When I run `sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sdd2` I get the following output:

```
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
rootfs contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Resize inode not valid.  Recreate<y>?
```

When I press "Y2 a bunch more solutions get proposed. At some point I get the option to press "A" to automatically say yes to everything. At the end I get the following output:

```
i_faddr for inode 2343 (???) is 4096, should be zero.
Clear? yes

i_faddr for inode 2347 (???) is 1, should be zero.
Clear? yes

Symlink ??? (inode #2345) is invalid.
Clear? yes

Error deallocating inode 2345: Corrupt extent header

rootfs: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
e2fsck: aborted

rootfs: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu#
```

Is there any way how I could properly fix this?

Comment: Pi devices are renowned for killing SD cards. You should probably just replace it.

Comment: @Mokubai is there a way to get my data back?

Comment: On Linux I'd be looking at using `dd` to copy an image of the card to a `.img` file and seeing what you can do with `testdisk`. Other than that I'm not sure, I've always assumed SD cards to be temporary or stuff I don't care about losing.